# Trigger Azure Pipeline on Merge

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a use case where I have two pipelines configured.  One for running tests which are triggered by a Pull Request and another pipeline that is handling deployment.  I am using Bitbucket cloud in Azure.

**Pipeline A** - Run through tests on PR.

**Pipeline B** - Deploy upon successful merge (approved pull request).

My current setup is to trigger pipeline A when a pull request is submitted.  This is no problem and works as intended.  The issue I am running into is with **Pipeline B**.  It is triggered regardless of whether the PR is approved or even merged.  I know that expected behavior for the CI trigger is to fire off with any action on the branch.  The PR trigger also doesn't fit my needs though as it would be redundant with **Pipeline A**.

What I would like to happen is since **Pipeline A** fires off on PR, a code reviewer will Approve and Merge the PR and only if the PR ends up getting merged into the Release branch is **Pipeline B** triggered.  Is this possible?

1. Developer completes code.
2. Developer submits PR against a **Release1.0** branch.
3. **Pipeline A** triggers.  Tests pass or fail.
4. Code reviewer approves and merges PR into **Release1.0** branch.
5. **Pipeline B** triggers and deploys.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

UPDATE: For those who bump into the same issue it's actually quite a simple fix.  Simply setting the trigger...

`pr: none`

in **Pipeline B** will do the trick.

To be clear, this solution is specific to Bitbucket Cloud and GitHub repositories only. The 'pr' syntax in YAML pipelines doesn't exist for Azure Repositories (use branch policy instead).

Comment: It would be nice if you could post the pipeline A and B so that we have an example to look at.

Comment: Yeah I would like to see the pipelines too please.

Comment: I shall third that request

Comment: As this was over a year ago the pipelines I had at the time are no longer relevant.  I can say that whatever pipelines I did have configured for A and B also don't matter.  There are plenty of examples out there on how to tackle pipeline A in this scenario.  Any starter one will do.

Comment: As posted above for pipeline B and the relevant YAML syntax all you want to do is add a trigger to watch for wherever you put release branches.  trigger: branches: include: - release/* for example.  And then add the pr: none right under it.  It will monitor for anything moved into release/* in the repo and run the pipeline without a pull request submitted.